# Attempting to Compile C++ App, Header File Not Found

Tags: c++, netbeans, mingw

I am attempting to compile a C++ application using Netbeans. This is the first C++ application I've built in a while. To my surprise as I have setup an environment and configured everything including Netbeans, Mingw, and Msys; the problem I have now while attempting to compile is a file note found error. The error message below states the isn't present but I can easily navigate to it in my Windows file system as well as in Netbeans as it a part of the project. I have no doubt there is some simple step I am overlooking. The file is a part of the Boost API and it's root folder is in the folder of my project which in turn is included as a source folder for my project (under Options).

```
g++    -c -g -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/addrman.o.d" -o build/Debug/MinGW-        Windows/addrman.o addrman.cpp
In file included from netbase.h:10:0,
             from addrman.h:7,
             from addrman.cpp:5:
serialize.h:19:48: fatal error: boost/type_traits/is_fundamental.hpp: No such file or      directory
 #include <boost/type_traits/is_fundamental.hpp>
```

Is this description and error message sufficient information? Thanks in advance for any help.
                                                ^

Comment: Nowhere did you mention what your `include` search path is set to. It doesn't matter if you can find it on your machine -- the compiler also has to find it, and it can't do that if the `include` search path doesn't state where the `boost` headers are located.

Comment: What particular Boost library are you trying to use?

Comment: Boost 1.55 is the version.

Comment: Boost is a collection of dozens of independent libraries...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to tell NetBeans about the Boost include directory. Open the project properties pop-up window, go to "Build -> C++ Compiler" and add the directory to the "Include Directories" line. This pop-up window should look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You compiler, g++ in this case, is not finding the header files due to them being in a non-standard location.  You need to use the `-I` flag to tell gcc where to look for the include files.

If you have your boost directory at, say, `C:\libraries\boost` then you would need to add the following to your compile line `-IC:\libraries\`  (and I would suggest putting boost some place like that so you can use it in multiple projects easily).

I don't use netbeans, but I would imagine that there is a place where you can specify additional include directories (and also library directories).

Comment: I tried using the 'additional [command line] options' in Netbeans: -IC:\local\boost_1_55_0\ and it doesn't work.